# Show that if $C(K)$ is separable, then $K$ is metrisable, for $K$ compact and Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions, metric-spaces

My question is simply as the title states:

> Let $(K,\tau)$ be a compact Hausdorff (topological) space. Show that if $C(K)$ is separable, then $K$ is metrisable.

Firstly, I appreciate that this is a fairly well-known question, and I can find people quoting it, but I can't find (or determine myself!) a proof.

All I have so far is that $C(K)$ is separable, so there exists a countable dense subset, $A$ say, of $C(K)$; so $\bar A = C(K)$. $A$ is countable, so I have enumerated $A$ as $A = \{a_1, a_2, \dots \}$. So I desire a metric $d:X \times X \rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $d$ induces the topology $\tau$ on $K$, but I can't see how to define $d$.

The question is in the Stone-Weierstrass section of my course, and I know that the converse is proved with S-W, but I can't see how to prove this way. If someone would be able to give me **a pointer**, then I'd be most appreciative.

If possible, I'd like a very minor hint that gives away as little as possible (I can always ask for a further hint). This is the first question I've done on metrising, so it may not be too difficult, just that I'm not used to it yet. (It seems like a good question so I don't want to waste the opportunity to learn from it!) Thanks in advance! :)

PS: Should I instead be looking for a homeomorphism from $K$ to a metric space instead? (Although I guess that this is basically the $d$ mentioned above...)

Comment: If $C(K)$ is separable, there is a countable family $\{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of continuous functions on $K$ that separates points with $f_n(K) \subset [0,1]$ for each $n$. Then look at something involving $\lvert f_n(x) - f_n(y)\rvert$. And note that every Hausdorff topology on $K$ that is coarser than $\tau$ must in fact coincide with $\tau$.

Comment: Or consider the function $x \mapsto (f_n(x))_n \in [0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ (using Daniel's functions). It's 1-1, continuous, ..

Comment: @DanielFischer How do I know that the family $\{f_n | n \in \Bbb N\}$ separates the points? Is this basically due to Stone-Weierstrass?

Comment: @SmileySam No. If $x \neq y$, there is some continuous function on $K$ that sends $x$ to $0$ and $y$ to $1$ (weak form of Tietze, or Urysohn's lemma). Some function $f_n$ is close to it, from denseness...

Comment: Ah yes, I had seen elsewhere that there was mention of Urysohn's lemma, but I didn't know how this could apply. I'll have a think about both yours and Daniel's suggestions.

Comment: A slightly strange request, but can you read the answer given below? I haven't read it yet because it looks reasonably long and I don't want it to give away any subtleties that I would benefit from discovering myself - after all, I'm only doing this to learn more!! :)

Comment: It's yet another way. It uses the Urysohn metrisation theorem that every second countable compact [= quasicompact and Hausdorff] space is metrisable, which is maybe a bigger gun than what Henno and I suggested. But an awesome cool gun.

Comment: Ok thanks. We haven't covered that in my course, so I'd have to prove it if I wanted to use it - probably not the most efficient answer to this question! I'm still trying to determine how to do it with yours or Henno's suggestion! One thing though: how can you claim that $f_n(K) \subseteq [0,1]$?

Comment: So, I have defined
$$d_n(x,y) = |f_n(x) - f_n(y)|,$$
which is a semi-metric (ie, satisfies all the metric axioms, except that we do not have "$d(x,y) = 0 \Rightarrow x = y$"; as least, 'semi-norms' are defined similarly - I guess that 'semi-metrics' are also...). I then defined
$$d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1 \over 2^n}d_n(x,y).$$
This is then a metric, since $F = \{f_n | n \in \Bbb N \}$ separates the points of $K$.

Comment: This is all ok. However, how do I know that the topology induced by $d$ is the same topology as that on $K$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $K$ is compact Hausdorff, $K$ is normal. I want to show that $K$ is second-countable, hence metrizability of $K$ will follow applying Urysohn's metrization Theorem.

Call $F \subseteq C(K)$ a dense countable subset. Call $B= \{ f^{-1} ((a,b)) : f \in F, a < b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$. $B$ is a countable family of open subsets of $K$. I want to show that $B$ is a basis for $\tau$.

Let $U$ any open set of $K$, $x \in U$. Since $K$ is normal, by the Urysohn Lemma there exists a continuous function $h : K \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x) = 0$ and $h(K\setminus U) = \{ 1 \}$.

Since $F$ is dense in $C(K)$, there exists $f \in F$ such that $\max_{t \in K} |f(t) - h(t)| < \frac{1}{5}$.

Then $$ x \in f^{-1} \left( \left( - \frac{1}{4} , \frac{1}{4} \right) \right) \subseteq U$$

So $U$ is a union of elements of $B$.

This means that $B$ is a countable basis for $\tau$.